# gradle - unpack zip in distribution

Tags: gradle

My gradle build is creating a distribution for me:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        contents {
            from ('src/resources/test.zip')
            // other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This results with test.zip and all the other stuff inside my created distribution. My question is how is it possible to unpack test.zip into the new distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `zipTree` to get the contents of the zip file:

```
contents {
    from (zipTree('src/resources/test.zip'))
    // other stuff
}
```